# Is there a way to delete empty values ​in a one-dimensional array in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

DataFrame Out put is like this

```
ID
61    0.07
62    0.07
63    0.07
64    0.10
65     NaN
66    0.08
67    0.07
68    0.07
69    0.07
70    0.07
Name: Con_R_mOhm, dtype: float64
```

in this case
I wanna make a chart using Seaborn Lib.
but having error massage
"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

so in this case how can i delete that NAN Value or change other value

best regard

my code is

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myDataSources = pyodbc.dataSources()
access_driver = myDataSources['MS Access Database']
driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
filepath = filename
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=access_driver,dbq=filepath,autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
table_list = list(crsr.tables())
table_name = 'GER100'
query = "SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name)
crsr.execute(query) # 쿼리 실행해서 데이터 소스 뽑아오는 작업
frame = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)
df = pd.DataFrame(frame)   # df 쿼리 잡아놓은것
df['date'] = df['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
ID = df['ID']
df = df.drop(['ID','Time'],axis=1) # 불필요 자료 드롭 시키는 방법
df.index = ID
a = df.loc[[65],['Con_R_mOhm']]
print(a)
sns.relplot(x=ID, y=df['Con_R_mOhm'] ,data = df) #데이터 그래프화
```

file link is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8tLRwrUcJVPnqHJj9nlnclvXatvyvjI/view?usp=sharing
and get massage like below

```
    Con_R_mOhm
ID            
65         NaN
C:\Users\bjkwack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3c584a0b4eb7> in <module>
     54 print(a)
     55 
---> 56 sns.relplot(x=ID, y=df['Con_R_mOhm'] ,data = df) #데이터 그래프화

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py in relplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, row, col, col_wrap, row_order, col_order, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, dashes, style_order, legend, kind, height, aspect, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   1700     g.map_dataframe(func, x, y,
   1701                     hue=hue, size=size, style=style,
-> 1702                     **plot_kws)
   1703 
   1704     # Show the legend

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in map_dataframe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    834 
    835         # Finalize the annotations and layout
--> 836         self._finalize_grid(args[:2])
    837 
    838         return self

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in _finalize_grid(self, axlabels)
    857     def _finalize_grid(self, axlabels):
    858         """Finalize the annotations and layout."""
--> 859         self.set_axis_labels(*axlabels)
    860         self.set_titles()
    861         self.fig.tight_layout()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in set_axis_labels(self, x_var, y_var)
    883         if x_var is not None:
    884             self._x_var = x_var
--> 885             self.set_xlabels(x_var)
    886         if y_var is not None:
    887             self._y_var = y_var

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in set_xlabels(self, label, **kwargs)
    894             label = self._x_var
    895         for ax in self._bottom_axes:
--> 896             ax.set_xlabel(label, **kwargs)
    897         return self
    898 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in set_xlabel(self, xlabel, fontdict, labelpad, **kwargs)
    245         if labelpad is not None:
    246             self.xaxis.labelpad = labelpad
--> 247         return self.xaxis.set_label_text(xlabel, fontdict, **kwargs)
    248 
    249     def get_ylabel(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in set_label_text(self, label, fontdict, **kwargs)
   1594         """
   1595         self.isDefault_label = False
-> 1596         self.label.set_text(label)
   1597         if fontdict is not None:
   1598             self.label.update(fontdict)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in set_text(self, s)
   1148         if s is None:
   1149             s = ''
-> 1150         if s != self._text:
   1151             self._text = str(s)
   1152             self.stale = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

thanks

Comment: It's not the NaN causing that message.  It's the way you've used the array.  Please show us the code that triggers this message.

Comment: Always share your piece of work to explain issues. This way community can better help.

Comment: @TimRoberts updated my code

Comment: @sharafjaffri updated my code

Answer (score 0):

for deleting NAN values use .dropna() method on series and for changing the NAN values use .replace() method.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pandas.Series(
        ['a','b','b', np.nan,np.nan ],
    )
    print(df.dropna())  ##delete NAN values
    print(df.replace(np.nan, 1)) ##replace NAN with some default value
```

Comment: Actually I would recommend using the `fillna` method instead of `replace`